# how to use glutStrokeCharacter regardless to the world's state

Tags: opengl, glut

im trying to print some text on my screen using GLUT with the following code :

```
glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(2, 2, 0);
        glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
        for (char *p = m_strFpsMessage; *p; p++)
            glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *p);

glPopMatrix();
```

in the above code im trying to print some information about my FPS status, the problem is that text is printed in a 3D world rather than a 2D. i would like to keep the text in a constant place regardless of my camera's position and its looking vector.

what am i doing wrong here?

edit : i tried to run the next code, but results were still in 3D

```
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
        glOrtho(constVal[0][0], constVal[1][0], constVal[0][1], constVal[1][0], 0.0001,10000);
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(2, 2, 0);
            glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
            for (char *p = m_strFpsMessage; *p; p++)
                glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *p);

        glPopMatrix();

    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change the projection and modelview to your needs when you need it. It's perfectly valid to start of completely new matrices anytime. You know: glLoadIdentity, and the rest.

---

#### Update: Pseudocode:

```
display_scene:
    glViewport(...)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    setup_projection()
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    setup_modelview()
    draw_scene()

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    setup_hud_projection()
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    setup_hud_modelview()
    draw_hud()
```

Pro-Tip: Do all OpenGL operations in the display function **and** *don't set up the projection and viewport in the window resize handler*. Once you perceive seting the projection as a regular operation and nothing special, a lot of seemingly difficult problems go away.

Comment: is there a need to switch to glOrtho?

Comment: @igalk: Since you want the text "in a constant place regardless of my camera's position and its looking vector," I'd say that yes, there's a need to use an orthographic projection. You could work out the math to make a perspective projection work, but you wouldn't be saving anything by taking the hard way.

Comment: i think i did a little mistake by asking this question in that way, im simply trying to display the number of fps on top-left level of the screen. the question is - do i need to calculate the math of the location of the text relatively to the perspective and so on, or is there something easier. either way.. i will need a hint/help code example, because im lost at the moment.

Comment: @igalk: Yes, there is something easier: Changing the projection.

Comment: @datenwolf: can you please add a small example? i'm not quite sure how to do it.